# Can't figure out why I received so many downvotes

Tags: support, specific-question, downvotes

I received so many downvotes so I had to remove this question. It's not a homework question. It's a problem that I faced when learning some algorithms. What could be the reason for the downvotes?

[image]

Comment: While I did not downvote, The first line of your question seems to state your are providing a answer in the form of a question, also compare the format of this meta post with your question. This meta post has a clear problem statement at the top, then followed by the "assets". your normal question has those parts fixed in, making it hard to see what is your actual question.

Comment: there is no answer here. The permutation seems to print the `str` values fine. But doesn't not store current/correct values of `str` to `$a` global array @Ferrybig

Comment: You just cannot assume that anybody here enjoys spending his free time debugging your code.  There are lots of existing solutions to generate permutations in Ruby, several at SO, it is not like your question is likely to ever help anybody else.  SO is not a personal debugging service.

Comment: @HansPassant I did my research. I tried to find question related to permutation in Ruby. But, ruby being very easy language has easy functions for every algorithm.

I was practicing this algorithm and there's are solution in C for same problem and not Ruby. If people at stackoverflow doesn't fix bugs which website would do so?

Comment: You're not listening. :-) People are telling you why your post was downvoted - because of the way it appears to those who read it. Clearly you didn't see it the same way, or you wouldn't have posted it like that; you should stop arguing (*there is no answer here*) and listen. Readers seldom see the post the same way the writer does. Hans is right; SO is not your own personal debugging service, and we're also not required to guess what it is you mean. If you have a question, make sure it's very clear what that question is rather than expecting us to read your mind to find out.

Comment: @AbhimanyuAryan they can help fix bugs, but they don't like to play "find my bug for me".  You should try to find you own bug and ask why is this not working as you expect.

Comment: Ok what I get from here is "I was clear with my question", "I didn't tried to debug the code on my own". Is that right?

Comment: all I can figure out is Lack of explanation. Thanks

Comment: No.  You were *not clear with your question* and you were *unclear where the problem was* and you *didn't debug the code yourself to try to find the problem*.

Comment: @KenWhite yes I get it now.

Answer (score 5):

The likely reason for downvotes is that your "question" does not actually pose a question. You need to be specific when positing a question and use a sentence that ends with a question mark.

Hope that gives some guidance.

EDIT FOLLOWING psubsee2003 comment

As psubsee2003 rightly says, you need to provide more information when asking the question, what is your code trying to achieve, etc, what is the stack trace. You need to ask it in such a way that the answerer needs no more further information.

Comment: I did put question mark at the end. I asked what is the bug in my code...look I have commented out the place which cause problem. Someone edited my question

Comment: i am not talking about the question mark in this question. I am talking about the missing question mark in your down voted question that this question refers to.

Comment: @AbhimanyuAryan I can't see the original, but unless that person significantly edited the question, even your original was a poor question.  Adding a question mark doesn't really make it a question.  You provided a block of code and the output, but you really didn't explain anything.  It would be difficult for someone to be able to understand your actual question without sitting next to you and discussing it.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I get it now. Lack of explanation